# How to start Sublime Text with selected project using a local .sublime-project file?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I may be missing the obvious, but can't seem to solve this fairly simple & typical case (with v3 build 3022 on Debian or XP, in case it matters):

- Start Sublime Text opening a project "myprj", specified on its command-line,
- using **default.sublime-project** located under that project's dir (say **"/repo/myprj"**),
- automatically re-opening the last open files of that project (i.e. its workspace),
- using **default.sublime-workspace** for that (also from the same project dir)
- but (obviously) not auto-opening any other files remembered from non-project sessions,
- and automatically saving all open files (to the above default.sublime-workspace) on exit.

Ideally:

1. $ `sublime_text --project /repo/myprj/default.sublime-project`

should just work. But it doesn't (see below).

Another approximation that seemed reasonable:

2. setting `"hot_exit"` and `"remember_open_files"` to `false`, and then invoking ST with:
3. $ `sublime_text --data /repo/myprj --project default.sublime-project`

But ST3 either doesn't find the project file (via `--data`), unless I chdir there first (`--data` seems to be [no longer supported](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command-line)?), and it either doesn't auto-open any workspace files from last time (despite a previous "Project / Save Workspace As..."), or, if I set "remember_open_files" back to true, it just re-opens the last open files *regardless* of the project given on the command line.

I guess the issue is the workspace file not being handled automatically for some reason, and I'm just missing some trivial step somewhere. (The [official docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/) (and also [the unofficial](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html)) seem to discuss [command-line switches for OS X only](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html), and asking for `--help` didn't actually help with this one.)

*(Please note: I wouldn't like to launch ST first, and then switch to some project from inside manually, and I also don't want to store the sublime-project/-workspace files outside of the prj. dir.)* Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try simply `sublime_text /path/to/project/file`? With a similar command in Windows 7, I've been able to achieve functionality like what's described [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=11209). I would imagine that the same would work in Debian, too, if all you're doing is running the `sublime_text` executable.

Comment: @Ninja: Hmm. It still fails to reopen the last workspace files. I think I misunderstand something. When I do a "Save All" or "Save Workspace As..." (to `./default.sublime-workspace`), even after a (hopefully redundant) "New Workspace for Project", it actually doesn't even seem to save the open files! At least I can't find the names of the open files in the workspace file (only see file names under "file_history"). ST either writes to some other workspace file, or still requires "remember_open_files":true. (But then how to prevent the mentioned false reloads?)

Comment: @Ninja: BTW, that hint of "Closing the duplicate project window that comes up" on the page you linked might as well be the key. (It just seems to be such an incredibly cumbersome workaround for such a basic use case for one of the best programmers' editors around, that I just can't believe it yet that a cleaner solution really doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

I seached for a solution for a similar problem these days and didn't find a proper way. So i created an automator app with a small apple script. Maybe this helps you too.

1. Open Automator and Choose news Application.
2. Create an action to start Sublime Text 2
3. Insert an action to perfom the following apple script:

```
delay 0.2

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Sublime Text 2"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "Project"
                tell menu "Project"
                    tell menu item "Recent Projects"
                        tell menu "Recent Projects"
                            click menu item "~/yourproject.sublime-project"
                            keystroke "p" using {command down, shift down}
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I've given up on Sublime Text and haven't used it recently, so I'm not sure: is this "Automator" a feature of ST, or some 3rd stuff?

Comment: I think it's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_%28software%29 Very useful for someone using Debian or XP.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking to do this, you can launch the built-in command line tool and launch it with a project like so (Mac OSX):

```
"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" --project "absolute-path-to-your.sublime-project"
```

Comment: Thanks, but systems like "Debian or XP" (Linux or Win, in general) is still the problem. OS X is for some unknown reason treated differently in this regard, and the support for it has been documented (as also hinted in the question: "official docs (and also the unofficial) seem to discuss command-line switches for OS X only").